# Ubuntu 14 display problem on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, display, mac, macbook, macbook-pro

I have just installed Ubuntu 14 on Virtualbox on my Macbook pro and I am facing some problems with its display. it seems that it is not properly scaled and i cant even access/change the display settings inside Ubuntu as the screen is partially trimmed. Anybody can guide me how to correct this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Devices` in the top-bar, then Click on `Install Guest Additions`.

Then run the install on the disk. After that, reboot ubuntu.

Hope this is helpful!